# GCP Batch not starting: [Batch Startup] Unsupported COS image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I'm trying to run a Instance template using the new Batch API

However after about 10 minutes, the instance gets stopped and delete for the following reason:

```
  - description: No VM has agent reporting correctly within the time window 600 seconds.
      VM state for instance j-ba57cada-aa64-44e9-bfa5-072fbc33f3a9-group0-0-pntw is
      2022/10/12-17:21:22+0000,startup,48,unsupported_cos.
```

I'm using the latest LTS COS version (cos-101-17162-40-5)

In the instance log I find the following entry, which is probably responsible:

```
startup-script: [Batch Startup] Unsupported COS image.
```

I checked where this is coming from and indeed it comes from the startup script testing if the directory **/var/lib/google/batch** exists, which does not.

Comment: Your question lacks detail and appears to be better targeted at Google Cloud Support than here. However, I attempted to repro your issue by create a Batch Job that runs a simple container (job). I assume, since you're targeting COS, that's your goal too. Interestingly, Batch used `projects/batch-custom-image/global/images/family/batch-cos-stable-official` to create an Instance Template to create Instance(s) to run the Batch Job.

Comment: Reading Google's docs for [Creating Batch Jobs using a Compute Engine Instance Template](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-job#create-job-instance-template) is imprecise and suggests that Templates can be arbitrary but this counters the idea that Batch must have requirements for Instance (Templates) in order that it be able to deploy Jobs onto them. A COS-based Instance Template can be configured to run an arbitrary number of containers, what then should Batch do with a such a Template? It's unclear.

Comment: For this reason I think that the documentation is deficient and `batch-cos-stable-official` provides a specific contract to Google Batch for running containers.